# How to render or Display complete screen in another blank screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native.
I have Two screens One is "Browse.js" and another is "Settings.js"
in "Browse.js" I have some tabs when User Click on The specific tab Specific page will open.
Now I want to show that Complete "Browse.js" screen in "Settings.js" by just rendering.
is it possible and How ? Means I want full control of "Browse.js" screen from "settings.js" by Just rendering "Browse.js" like this =>

```
return(
  <Browse />
);
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question a bit.

Comment: I just want to create same working screen as "Browse.js"  in "Setting.js" By just Writing One line like this ==> return( <Browse /> ); , is it possible , How ?

Answer (score 0):

As I get understanding from your question you need to render your `Browse.js` code inside the `Settings.js`, You can render like this.

```
Import Browse from 'Your file path' // Import like this



   export default function(){
        return(
          <React.Fragment>
              <Settings />
              <Browse />
         </React.Fragment>)
   }
```

Comment: Should I create separate file for that code if not , then where should I write this code mean in which file??

Comment: Now this Error is coming =  undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') when click on tab (that tab exist in Browse.js ) to open specific page

Comment: Browse.js Code??

Comment: Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65595240/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-navigation-navigate-cant-render-prope

Comment: you are not getting navigation prop in your component, Can you please add all of your code here and share me the link with the problem you are facing.
https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: I ADD settings.js also please check that link again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226970/discussion-between-sohil-shaikh-and-waheed-akhtar).